# How do I access the list of generated cuts after presolving the model?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, scip

I would like to access the model information after presolving. Specifically, I would like to see the list of cuts that were added to the model during the presolving phase. Is there a way to access this list of cuts?

Answer (score 0):

If cuts get added to the model during presolving, then they would be added as constraints (since the LP has not been created at that stage). Note that this does not happen very often in presolving.

I would suggest simply looking at the transformed problem and to check which constraints have been added.